# Predicting with a machine learning model while preserving the privacy

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs, machine-learning

Imagine Alice has trained a machine learning model. She wants to store her model in a blockchain so that everyone can use it; however, she wants her model to be private so that no one can steal her trained model.

Is there any way that a model can be used for prediction only while being private? For example, is there any homomorphic encryption method for predicting with an encrypted model?